# Kendo UI grid edit mode columns styles

Tags: html, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid with a popup editable property. I would like to make my dropdown columns wider when I'm add/edit mode, but I cannot seem to change the widths. I can indeed change the widths in the grid itself but not in edit mode.

Does it have to do with some kind of Edit Template ? I can't find the documentation for it.

thanks.
Bob

Here's my sample grid :

```
       positGrid = $("#positGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: datasource,
        toolbar: [
            { name: "create", text: "Add Position" }
        ],
        columns: [{
            field: "PositionId", 
        },
        {
            field: "Portfolio", 
            editor: portfolioDropDownEditor, template: "#=Portfolio#"
        },
        {
            field: "Instrument",
            width: "220px",
            editor: instrumentsDropDownEditor, template: "#=Instrument#", 
        },
        {
            field: "NumOfContracts",
        },
        {
            field: "BuySell",
            editor: buySellDropDownEditor, template: "#=BuySell#"
        },
        {
            command: [
              {
                  name: "edit",
                  click: function (e) {           
                  }
              },
              "destroy"
            ]
        },
        ],
        sortable: true,
        editable: "popup",
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wire up [edit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-edit) event to set dropdown options:

```
name: "edit",
    click: function (e) {  
        if (!e.model.isNew()) {         
            var dropdown = e.container.find("input[name=Portfolio]").data("kendoDropDownList");
            dropdown.list.width(500);
        }
        }
```

Comment: Just one clarification please. The property e.model.isNew() is evaluated to TRUE when I click on my "Add", and then TRUE again when I click on the inline "Edit" button. Is that because it hasn't yet been SAVED, so the grid still considers it NEW ?

Comment: You are right, what [api](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#methods-isNew) says is: "If the value of the field specified is equal to the default value (specified through the fields configuration) the model is considered as new."